# use directive return value

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have this dirctive that return title or null , how can i use this return value in html component  ???

```
 element:ElementRef;
@Input() pageTabTitle:string;
constructor(el:ElementRef) { this.element =el; }

ngOnChanges(): void {
setTimeout(() => {
  this.hasTooltip(this.pageTabTitle);
  })
}
hasTooltip(title:string) {
if(this.isOverflown()) {
  return title;
} else {
  return null;
}
}
isOverflown():boolean {
return this.element.nativeElement.scrollWidth > 
this.element.nativeElement.clientWidth;
}
```

I want to use this value in tooltip title

```
[attr.data-original-title]="" // here I want to set return directive value
```

Comment: I don't know what do you want. If you want to use in a directive some attribute of the element, I think you can try: this.element.nativeElement.data-original-title, but generally in a directive we using @ Input() to get the parameters

Answer (score 0):

I think your directive doesn't have @Output - it couldn't return something:)
If you want that it emit some event with value, you should @Output property and emit it when you need.

[Angular Io](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-listens-for-child-event)

Comment: how can i use hasTooltip(title:string) returned value in component that have this directive ???